# How to rename objects with Django

Tags: django

I have an answer about renaming objects on my webinterface.For example i have a table named "Map" and i have many obejcts in there(Map object,Map object,Map object,Map object,Map object,Map object) How is it possible to rename them?I mean i want to have something like (Map Asia,Map Europe,Map America,Map Africa and so on) for every object to give him a different name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**unicode** can help you.

```
class Map(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=20)
    ....

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Map %s' % self.name
```

Comment: Please use 'Map {}'.format(self.name) for python 3 compatibility :)

Comment: @patrick no, the %s format is [present in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting), and is not deprecated.

Comment: Thanks a lot Likeon!That was exactly what i wanted :)